# Can I parallelise a Python function that returns None with Ray?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, symlink, joblib, ray

I have a function that takes in a filename and creates a symlink in a target directory if that filename exists in the "source" directory:

```py
def _symlink_photos(photo_name: str, photos_dir: Path, target_dir: Path) -> None:
    """
    Given a string, checks if it exists in `photos_dir`,
    then creates a symlink in `target_dir`
    """

    photo_path: Path = photos_dir / photo_name
    if photo_path.exists():
        (target_dir / photo_name).symlink_to(photo_path)
```

This function is meant to be used to iterate over a somewhat big list of filenames (some 70k), like so:

```py
def main() -> None:
    """
    Given a list of photos, checks if they exist in the source directory,
    and symlinks them into the target directory.
    """

    for photo_name in tqdm(photo_list):
        _symlink_photos(photo_name, photo_dir, target_dir)
```

The brute-force/for-loop approach is taking me too long (tqdm estimates over a day), so I was wondering how to parallelise this job. I knew I could use [ray](https://calmcode.io/ray/speed.html), but in order to use it I would need to write my code like this:

```py
futures = [_symlink_photos.remote(photo_name, photo_dir, target_dir) for photo in photo_list]
result = ray.get(futures)
```

Yet this does not make sense to me, as my function does not return anything. Can I still use ray? Should I switch to something else, like joblib/threading?

Another alternative I was thinking of is to parallelise the "check if photo_name exists in the source dir" part with ray, i.e. to retrieve the list of photos that actually are in the target directory. Only then I would create the symlinks, hopefully taking less time...

Comment: What does `ray.get` return? Just because a function returns a value doesn't mean you have to care about that value.

Comment: However, your bottle neck here is how quickly your machine can create 70k symlinks, which isn't necessarily as fast as your program can *request* 70k symlinks be created. If your program can continue doing other CPU-bound stuff while other parts continue churning through I/O, great. Otherwise, it's not going to matter how quickly you can get to the point where you have to wait for the symlinks to finish being created.

Comment: thank you for the comment! `ray.get()` spits this error message: `ValueError: 'object_refs' must either be an object ref or a list of object refs`. indeed, the problem is how fast my machine can create the symlinks... since it's an I/O problem, maybe using multithreading/async could yield better results?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ray in the way that you described. The `ray.get` call will simply return a list of `None` values, which you can ignore.

You can also look up `ray.wait` which can be used to wait for certain tasks to finish without actually retrieving the task outputs.